# Multer isn't saving pictures

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I have router with multer-settings -

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');
const config = require('config');

const router = express();
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'picture_db');
    },
    filename(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024
    },
    fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
        const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        if (ext !== '.jpg' && ext !== '.jpeg' && ext !== '.png') {
            const err = new Error('Extention');
            err.code = 'EXTENTION';
            return cb(err);
        }
        cb(null, true);
    }
}).single('file')

router.post('/image',
    async(req, res) => {
        try {
            let status;

            upload(req, res, err => {
                let error = '';

                if (err) {
                    if (err.code === 'LIMIT_FILE_SIZE') {
                        error = 'file size';
                    }
                    if (err.code === 'EXTENTION') {
                        error = 'file extention';
                    }
                    status = error;
                }
            });

            return res.status(200).json({
                msg: status || 'OK',
            });
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                msg: "a"
            });
        }
    }
);

module.exports = router;
```

And a folder in the project root - `picture_db`.

Also I have a postman-query -

[image]

Why the picture isn't saving in `picture_db`?

Comment: Is there any error popping up?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara, no, servers answer is `'OK'`

Comment: I think you should try to print error in your if statement using console.log. I am pretty sure there is an issue file. Also, try to get the filename in filefilter. check if your API is receiving Data.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara, I've tryed and get this - `MulterError: Unexpected field`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are doing is wrong. When you are uploading your file, you are not naming the key of your file.

Instead, you should add the key in postman to 'file' and upload the file and run it.

[image]

Comment: I was thinking, what is this argument for?)

Comment: your data is of type object, which has key-value pair. So, you need to actually add key for the data you will be sending.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I made an incorrect sentence. I wanted to say that I did not know what this argument was for, but thanks to your answer I learned